# Where can i run uncompilled scripts?

Tags: android, python, scripting, layer, sl4a

The question:
Can i run an uncompilled python script (sl4a) on any android phone?
Description of idea: I wrote a script that manipulates with qr-codes. I am thinking about putting a script inside the code read that and write it to a file named myqrscript.py or something then call myqrscript.qrcontent() wich is defined inside the code. Can i do that?

Comment: Have a look at Kivy, which is a framework that will let you write apps in Python: http://kivy.org/#home

Comment: @ThomasK: Please post your answer as a proper answer so we can up vote it properly.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (I don't have a smartphone), SL4A scripts can only be run if you have SL4A already installed.

Have a look at [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home), which is a framework that will let you write apps in Python.

Answer (score 0):

To run Python scripts on your Android phone all you have to do is install SL4A and this is how you do that:

To install SL4A, you will need to enable the "Unknown sources" option in your device's "Application" settings, download the .apk and install it either by accessing http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/ from your computer and click the qr-code or directly from your phone and click the qr-code and then run the downloaded .apk file.

After installing SL4A:

- press the Home button
- press Add button
- go to Interpreters
- press Home button again
- press Add again
- pick Python Interpreter and install it

and after that a new screen will appear with an Install button on the top, press it and it will download Python 2.6.2, at the moment, for you. Optionally there is a button so that you can download a few more Python modules.

After these steps you are ready to go. You will be able to create Python scripts using SL4A and run the directly on your phone without "compiling" them, if that's your worry. It also makes the .pyc files if those are the ones you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

exactly what you want is documented here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/SharingScripts